# Comparing indices for symbolic expression in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a (2x2) symbolic matrix in matlab, and substituted one element.

```
a = sym('a', [2 2])
a = subs(a, a(1,2), a(2,1))
```

Then the symbolic matrix looks like

> a = [ a1_1, a2_1]
>         [ a2_1, a2_2]

Now I want to compare the two elements in each row whether their second indices are same or not. For example, if their second indices are same, we substitute them to 10, otherwise no change. After this operation, a should be changed like

> a = [ 10, 10]
>         [ a2_1, a2_2]

How should I write script?

Comment: @bushmills If I can get the index of a symbolic elements, for example if there is an INDEX function which returns the indices of input, INDEX(a2_1) = [2,1], I can solve the problem, but I couldn't find that sort of function in matlab manual.

Comment: are you searching for the [find](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html)-function?